# JQuery Mobile navigation .. is the left nav really not collapsible?

Tags: jquery, css, html, mobile, navigation

just a quick question to see if anyone has pondered this one...

if you go to http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html and look at the collapsible navigation (scroll to the last example, at the bottom aka "content-primary") it looks lovely.. but it doesn't seem possible to implement this "mechanic" of sub menus within the left-nav when declared as "content-secondary"

so my question is.. why not? Surely there must be a way?